# Umi-Cms не выводится картинка в карточке

Tags: php, java, html, cms, umi

Первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой, так что не топите) На сайте есть меню в виде карточек [image: введите сюда описание изображения], в каждой карточке картинка, которая вставляется через шаблон. Из 7 картинок 4 вставляются как надо, а 3 берут левую картинку. Сам код идентичен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Права на папку стоят правильные.(0755) При этом левая картинка всегда вставляется одна и та же и если ее удалить из папки , она создается заново, как будто шаблон ее сам создает. Может кто знает или сталкивался с таким? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ну вообще похоже на превьюшку, которая макросом генерируется system/makeThumbnail() или system/makeThumbnailFull(). Еще может быть кеш браузера.

Comment: так, ну кеш я чистил) а вот с превьюшкой я пробежал поиском по system/makeThumbnail по xsl файлам и там ни чего не нашел криминального

Answer (score 0):

Миниатюра определенно создается макросом [system/makeThumbnail()](http://dev.docs.umi-cms.ru/spravochnik_makrosov_umicms/virtualnyj_modul_system/system_makethumbnail/#content) или [system/makeThumbnailFull()](http://dev.docs.umi-cms.ru/spravochnik_makrosov_umicms/virtualnyj_modul_system/system_makethumbnailfull/).

Когда Вы чистите папку images/cms/thumbs, Вы удаляете лишь временные изображения и макрос создает их заново.

Нужно пройтись по шаблонам сайта и найти, где макрос вызывается, а затем проверить, что он принимает в качестве первого параметра (путь к изображению-оригиналу).

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за ответ